# How can dnsmasq be listening if it's not running?

Tags: dns, dnsmasq

`service --status-all`  shows `dnsmasq` with a (-) in front of it indicating it's not running.

Yet when I try and run `sudo dnsmasq` I  get the message `dnsmasq: failed to create listening socket for 127.0.0.1: Address already in use`

So I check what's listening on `127.0.0.1` with `sudo ss -alpn sport = 53 src 127.0.0.1` and I get the output:

```
TCP | LISTEN | 0 | 32 | 127.0.0.1:53 | 0.0.0.0:* | users:(("dnsmasq",pid=3307,fd=5))
```

How  can it be listening if it's not running?

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps:

### Services

Compare `service --status-all` output with

`systemctl list-units --type=service`.

### Listening ports and applications

Install `net-tools` and display the list of listening ports including process numbers and names. The `nestat` is similar to `ss`, but more compact:

```
sudo apt-get install net-tools

sudo netstat -lntp
```

Search for both the port 53 and the dnsmasq name. The `dnsmasq` can use two ports (DNS and DHCP). Verify no listening application with `dnsmasq` and no port 53 are listed. If one or both are still listed, display processes by

```
ps -ef
ps -aux
```

eventually with full line contents saved in text files to later analysis and filtering using `grep`:

```
ps -ef  > list1.txt
ps -aux > list2.txt
ps -eux > list3.txt
```

Search for process number got from `netstat` and follow its parent process(es) in list to get order and way how they were started. Process listing will show you the `dnsmasq` process(es) including configuration file names, paths and other details.

**Some applications can be started as a service or as a standalone process**. Therefore a collision may occur between two similar processes by this way.

Kill manually unwanted process to free-up port for listening and try start dnsmasq by way you need.

```
sudo kill -9 <process_number>
```